# Unable to access electronics Spartacus Demo SIte

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am trying to access demo spartacus site, I can see the login page but i am not able to login or register.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { translationChunksConfig, translations } from "@spartacus/assets";
import { defaultOccConfig, FeaturesConfig, I18nConfig, OccConfig, provideConfig, SiteContextConfig } from "@spartacus/core";
import { defaultB2bOccConfig } from "@spartacus/setup";
import { defaultCmsContentProviders, layoutConfig, mediaConfig } from "@spartacus/storefront";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
  ],
  providers: [provideConfig(layoutConfig), provideConfig(mediaConfig), ...defaultCmsContentProviders, provideConfig(<OccConfig>{
    backend: {
      occ: {
        baseUrl: 'https://api.coinscf0-itelligen1-d1-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/',
         prefix:'/occ/v2/'
      }
    },
  }), provideConfig(<SiteContextConfig>{
    context: {
      urlParameters: ['baseSite', 'language', 'currency'],
      baseSite: ['electronics-spa'],
      currency: ['USD'],
      language: ['en']
    },
  }), provideConfig(<I18nConfig>{
    i18n: {
      resources: translations,
      chunks: translationChunksConfig,
      fallbackLang: 'en'
    },
  }), provideConfig(<FeaturesConfig>{
    features: {
      level: '6.0'
    }
  }), provideConfig(defaultOccConfig)]
})
export class SpartacusConfigurationModule { }
```

with the above configuration, I am not able to login or register into the demo site, How can i login into electronics demo site?What are the default credentials?

Comment: do you get any kind of error? either in the console of the browser, or in the logs of the backend system?

Comment: @Yoni Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:4200/PROFILE_TAG_LOAD_URL_PLACEHOLDER' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: dont have backend, I am using demo site https://spartacus-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:8443/   @Yoni

Comment: @Yoni now i dont see any errors but i am not able to login or register, No call is being made on login or registe.